# SSH Tunnel doesn't work

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh, ubuntu-server, ssh-tunnel

I use following command to make a ssh tunnel to my ubuntu server:

```
ssh -fNg -L 8888:127.0.0.1:22 -p 1000 username@server-address  -v
```

Then I set OSX http and https proxy to 127.0.0.1:8888

And I got following error:

> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
>
> Protocol mismatch.

What is the problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: what do your really need to do? your command means forward local port 8888 to remote port 22, and also your server listen on port 1000 for ssh???!!!

Comment: you could also examine what is going on in wireshark with filters.

Comment: -1 It's not good to leave a question hanging not trying to diagnose the problem. This question would be very valuable if it had an answer that really got to the bottom of the error. Without an answer it isn't very valuable.

Comment: Can you mark an answer as solution?

Answer (score 1):

-L 8888:localhost:22 will forward your local port 8888 to the ssh server's port 22. As long as there is no squid server or another proxy running, it will not work.

SSH can provide a socks proxy, which you can use in order to browse through your ssh tunnel.

```
ssh -fNg -D 8888 -p 1000 username@server-address  -v
```

Just set your proxy after connecting:

```
localhost:8888
```

Comment: It connects but I see an error in my browser!

Comment: @AmirAbbasKashani did you tell your browser that it's a socks proxy rather than a regular http[s] proxy?  and what error do you see?

Comment: @barlop ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED

Answer (score 1):

> You write  "I use following command to make a ssh tunnel to my ubuntu
>   server:
>
> ssh -fNg -L 8888:127.0.0.1:22 -p 1000 username@server-address  -v

OK so you would need to have an SSH server on port 1000

OK so the client program would be connecting to port 8888 and whatever it sends there will be forwarded to port 22(22 being the port commonly used for ssh).

I guess if you were trying to tunnel ssh within ssh that might make sense, though I can't off the top of my head think of a need for that!

> Then I set OSX http and https proxy to 127.0.0.1:8888"

No, you already have SSH opening a port listening on port 8888.  You can't have another thing listening on that port.

If you put the http[s] proxy on port 22 of the destination machine(server-address), and configure your web browser to use proxy 127.0.0.1:8888 then your web browser could connect to port 8888 and that will be forwarded to the http proxy on port 22 of the destination machine.  When you did `-L 8888:127.0.0.1:22` it means you have to have something listening on port 22 of the destination machine. And you might want to change 22 to something more sensible like 8080  I haven't tested it but I think it'd work

Alternatively, SSH does have a -D option too that acts as a SOCKS proxy that can do HTTP[s] , but tell the web browser to connect to a SOCKS proxy rather than a regular HTTPS.  So I suppose then like the line David said `ssh -fNg -D 8888 -p 1000 username@server-address  -v`  The -fNg  and -v isn't essential of course.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and I got the same error

Comment: @AmirAbbasKashani hmph, i'm not familiar with that error.  But aside from trying a different command like what davidbaumann suggests.  What  you could do is some troubleshooting to really find the cause of that error - that would be helpful for others too, to really find the route of the problem. Try to see if you can adjust your long line, such that you simplify it and still get the error  e.g. remove the unnecessary -fNg see if you still get the error. Remove the -L 8888:127.0.0.1:22, and see if still an error.

Comment: And try to adjust your long line from the other end, make it really simple like ssh username@server -p 1000 -v and see if you still get an error And if no error, then try to build it up to getting an error.  And try from `$ nc dscomp 22 <ENTER>`  When I do that it says SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7